# How can you hide a TabBar in SwiftUI and retain toolbarItems?

Tags: xcode, swiftui, tabview

I would like to hide the TabBar of my TabView in SwiftUI when pushing from one view to another just like in pretty much any chat app other than Messages.

I have seen several approaches using third party libraries however I am looking for a native solution.

This closest I have come is the TabView nested in a NavigationView.  This seems to work fine and the NavigationTitle can be set however I have not found a way to set the toolbarItem.

```
@State var navTitle: String = ""

NavigationView {
    TabView {
        ViewA()
            .tabItem {
                Label("TabA", systemImage: "some.image")
            }
        ViewB()
            .tabItem {
                Label("TabB", systemImage: "some.image")
            }
        ViewC()
            .tabItem {
                Label("TabC", systemImage: "some.image")
            }
    }
    .navigationTitle($navTitle) // change nav title in tabbed views
}
```

If I were to use this approach to ensure that the tabBar hides when pushing new views in the ViewA/B/C, how would I be able to place toolBarItems in navigationBarTrailing in the navigationBar for ViewA/B/C?

I would need the buttons in these toolBarItems to be accessible in ViewA/B/C otherwise I would be creating viewModels in the TabBarView and passing around which I want to avoid.

If there is just a way to hide the TabBar when pushing to another view I can go back to having the navigationView nested inside the TabView which would make things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

What I've done is a very hacky solution but it seems to work until they have a way to hide the TabBar:

```
NavigationView {
    TabView {
        ViewA()
            .tabItem {
                Label("TabA", systemImage: "some.image")
            }
        ViewB()
            .tabItem {
                Label("TabB", systemImage: "some.image")
            }
        ViewC()
            .tabItem {
                Label("TabC", systemImage: "some.image")
            }
    }
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
}
```

And then in each of your views you can add a NavigationView. Seems to work well although obviously not the ideal approach.

Comment: While Swift is (nowadays) open source, unfortunately SwiftUI isn't. I understand why, but still. Swift, currently 5.3.3, has been updated 5 times since WWDC 2020. SwiftUI? I'm not even sure if Apple uses versioning, but let's say it's 2.x? My take, I wish you luck that WWDC 2021 will introduce something less tacky. (I still use UIKit solely because I don't care about Apple Watch or Mac hardware and there were so many "gaps" for my apps.)